# Converting binary values to be numerical for many features using preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

Tags: python

I know I can convert binary numbers into numerical values for all my features using the code below, but how can I change all my features to be numerical values without using `feature = le.fit_transform(list(data["feature"]` for every single feature? Is there another way to write this more concisely?

```
data = pd.read_csv("car.data")    
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()    
buying = le.fit_transform(list(data["buying"]    
maint = le.fit_transform(list(data["maint"]    
door = le.fit_transform(list(data["door"]    
persons = le.fit_transform(list(data["persons"]    
lug_boot = le.fit_transform(list(data["lug_boot"]    
safety = le.fit_transform(list(data["safety"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a dict comprehension.

```
data = pd.read_csv("car.data")
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
result = {
    label: le.fit_transform(list(data[label]))
    for label in (
        "buying", "maint", "door", "persons",
        "lug_boot", "safety"
    )
}
```